# VBA error PasteSpecial Method of Range Class failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have this error all the time, even though I tried removing selection etc. Before this I update some cells and then the code copies and selects 7 rows (it was supposed to select 10) and before pasting gives the error. Where the code gets stuck is

```
Range("C4:AN" & Range("B5").Value).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Please help

```
Sub Refresh()
Call Confirm

Dim F As New FDSOfficeAPI_Server
Application.Iteration = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Supply Chain").Select
Range("C1:BA10000").Select
V = F.RefreshSelectedFDSCodes
Range("B1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Sheets("Supply Chain").Select

    Range("C4:AN4").Copy
    Range("C4:AN" & Range("B5").Value).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("BD4:CO4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("BD4:CO" & Range("BC5").Value).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("DE4:EO4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("DE4:EO" & Range("DD5").Value).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: What's the value of B5 when it fails?  FYI you have a lot of repeated code here which could be moved to a separate sub like `Sub CopyFormats(rngFrom as Range, rngTo As Range)`  That would simplify your main code and make troubleshooting easier.

Comment: B5 is the cell with the value that tells until which row it should paste.

Comment: Value of B5 not purpose of B5.

Comment: Ohh sorry. It is 10

Comment: With the added code it's not obvious where the problem might be, unless `F.RefreshSelectedFDSCodes` is somehow still running when the rest of the code get executed.

Comment: I don't thin that is still running. It should finish, as the update progress box also disappears. However, the problem is still the same line (even if I now put it as a separate macro and call it afterwards).

Comment: Sorry I can't say what the cause might be - it does seem related to the previous code but I don't know exactly what that does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would be easier to maintain if you move the repeated parts to a separate sub.  Try something more like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    FillDownFormats Range("C4:AN4"), Range("B5").Value
    FillDownFormats Range("BD4:CO4"), Range("BC5").Value
    FillDownFormats Range("DE4:EO4"), Range("DD5").Value
End Sub

'Fill down the formats from rngSource to fill total of 'numRows' rows
Sub FillDownFormats(rngSource As Range, numRows As Long)
    
    rngSource.Offset(1, 0).Resize(numRows-1).ClearFormats 'clear any existing formatting
    rngSource.Copy
    rngSource.Resize(numRows).PasteSpecial _
                    Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I have some follow up questions (as I am completely new to VBA). Won't I then have more than one macro? I am trying to build this part of the code to an existing macro. Also, could that be a source of the problem, that I am doing something before this, as if I run just the part of the code that I posted here (by itself) it works?

Comment: Having more than one macro is not a problem, but what I posted above is just an example of how you could modify your existing code - I can only see what you posted, so  I'm just addressing that part of the overall process.  If you think what you're doing prior to copying the formats might be a problem, then you can add that to your post.

Comment: Hi, this works perfectly fine, except if the conditional formatting is already in the cells. Another way on how to trigger the error (which says PasteSpecial method of Range class failed) is to first choose B5=20 and then B5=10. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Try the edit above - it will clear any existing formats below `rngSource` before the copy/paste

Comment: Hi Tim, just one more question. I just realized that the clearFormats doesn't really clean them. Any thoughts on how to correct that?

Comment: Can you provide a specific example where ClearFormats fails to clear a format?

Comment: Let's say that first I have 20 rows and then I change it to 10. If i understand correctly, this should clear formatting for all of the rows bellow 1 and paste it until row 10. However, if I write something in Row 11, the formatting still exists.

Comment: If you only tell the method to fill 10 rows then how would it know there are formats below that to clear?  If you want to clear formats from more of the sheet then you can do that. `rngSource.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1000).ClearFormats` for example